# TypeError: __init__() got multiple values for argument 'kernel_size'

Tags: tensorflow, keras, keras-layer, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

I am getting the below error while executing my program ...

```
def conv2d(x, output_dim, k_size=5, stride=2, stddev=0.02, name="conv2d"):
    #conv = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(x, output_dim, kernel_size=k_size, 
                                   strides=[stride, stride], padding="SAME", 
                                   kernel_initializer=init(stddev=0.02), name=name)
    conv = tf.compat.v1.layers.Conv2D(x, output_dim, kernel_size=k_size, 
                                      strides=[stride, stride], padding='SAME', 
                                      kernel_initializer=init(stddev=0.02), name=name)
```

**Error**

> File "/nfs/s-iibi54/users/skuanar/Downloads/VAE-GAN-Autoencoding-Beyond-Pixels-Using-a-Similarity-Metric-master/vaegan.py", line 20, in conv2d
>   conv = tf.compat.v1.layers.Conv2D(x, output_dim, kernel_size=k_size, strides=[stride, stride], padding='SAME', kernel_initializer=init(stddev=0.02), name=name)
>   TypeError: init() got multiple values for argument 'kernel_size'

Answer (score 2):

You are passing `x` to the layer's `__init__` method. That's not how Keras layers work.

You should pass `x` by **calling** a layer that already exists:

```
def conv2d(x, output_dim, k_size=5, stride=2, stddev=0.02, name="conv2d"):
    #conv = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(output_dim, kernel_size=k_size, 
                                   strides=[stride, stride], padding="SAME", 
                                   kernel_initializer=init(stddev=0.02), name=name)(x)
    conv_output = tf.compat.v1.layers.Conv2D(output_dim, kernel_size=k_size, 
                                      strides=[stride, stride], padding='SAME', 
                                      kernel_initializer=init(stddev=0.02), name=name)(x)
```

Assuming `x` is your input tensor.

---

This is the same as:

```
conv_layer = Conv2D(output_dim, kernel_size=k_size, 
                    strides=[stride, stride], padding="SAME", 
                    kernel_initializer=init(stddev=0.02), name=name)
conv_layer_output_tensor = conv_layer(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the [keras docs](https://keras.io/layers/convolutional/), the `Conv2D` second argument is `kernel_size`. You are calling this method with the second argument and the `kernel_size` named argument as well

Answer (score 0):

As stated in [Tensorflow 2.0 Conv2D documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Conv2D), the second argument is `kernel_size`, so your `output_dim` is conflicting with it. The right way to use Conv2D is to initialize it first and then pass to it its input tensor like this:

```
def conv2d(x, output_dim, k_size=5, stride=2, stddev=0.02, name="conv2d"):
    conv = tf.compat.v1.layers.Conv2D(output_dim, kernel_size=k_size, strides=[stride, stride], padding='SAME', kernel_initializer=init(stddev=0.02), name=name)
    y = conv(x)
```

You could also get the output tensor in one line as done in the tutorial [The Keras functional API in TensorFlow](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/functional):

```
y = tf.compat.v1.layers.Conv2D(output_dim, kernel_size=k_size, strides=[stride, stride], padding='SAME', kernel_initializer=init(stddev=0.02), name=name)(x)
```